# Update error 80072f8f and daylight saving time

Tags: update

I have Lumia 1320 running OS version 8.10.14157.200, I also have enrolled in "Preview for developers".

I have trouble fetching latest update, my phone reports error 80072f8f.

Similar error in desktop Windows is usually caused by wrong system time (OS is unable to establish SSL connection with Microsoft servers). I live in Moscow (where we've recently got rid from DST adjustments and where current time should be UTC+3 and not UTC+4 as earlier).

To address this I've changed my time zone to Kuwait (UTC+3) manually. But I still get this error.

It is quite funny because i know for sure that the update I am not getting contains, among others, time zone fixes :)  But I can't grab one, no matter which region, time zone or whatever I choose. This is a hopeless loop.

Is there a way to force an update to be downloaded and applied? Thanks.